# How to show hint for a disabled TDBEdit?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, tooltip, delphi-2007, hint

I have a TDBEdit that is not enabled and thus not showing the Hint.
What would be the best way to have it display the Hint while staying disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is overlaying the TDBEdit with a fully transparent control that has ShowHint set to True and a Hint property set.

Comment: That's more or less the workaroound I'm currently using with a graphic control just underneath the disabled TDBEdit...

Comment: I agree, it is simply a dirty hack, but disabled controls never will popup hints. Just another idea to not disable the control but play with the colors and set the readonly property?

Answer (score 0):

Drop your disabled TWinControl (TDBEdit is a TWinControl) onto an **enabled** TWinControl container (a TPanel for example) and set the TPanel hint to the desired value.

Comment: I prefer the more lightweight approach of a TGraphicControl (no window handle, no change in Parenthood)

Comment: Yeah but I find my way less "dirty" than an invisible control over the grid :)

Comment: You actually probably aren't using a window handle just to have a grid on it.  I did some tests to see what the limit was on handles but I ran out of memory first.  Handles was a concern back in Windows 95 and 98.